# How to generate a choices tuple for django models field to use in a form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Trying to create a choice field based on another model

I want my choices to be mapped like `username: first_name + last_name`

When I try `username: last_name` it does work

I tried doing something like this(Note, I am adding on user_choices and choices=user_choices. The model already existed before me making these changes.)

This works:

```
he_user_choices = tuple(User.objects.values_list('username', 'last_name'))
```

Here's what my models.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

owner_choices = tuple(User.objects.values_list('username', 'first_name' + 'last_name'))


class ErrorEvent(models.Model):
    """Error Event Submissions"""
    event_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Owner", blank=True, choices=owner_choices)
```

and here's my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ErrorEvent


class ErrorEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ErrorEvent
        # fields =
        exclude = ['event_id']
        widgets = {
            'owner': forms.Select(),
        }
```

Currently the owner_choices doesn't work, I get an error that says:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Any recommendations on what else I can try, or how would I go about fixing my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please work with a `ForeignKey`, not an `IntegerField`, then we can work with a `ModelChoiceField` in the form.

Comment: I'd love to, but that's no possible right now!

Comment: because.........?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do *not* work with an `IntegerField` to refer to an object. A `ForeignKey` will check referential integrity, and furthermore it makes the Django ORM more expressive.

You thus can implement this with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class ErrorEvent(models.Model):
    event_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name='Owner',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

This will work with a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) that automatically will query the database to render options. This also means that if you add a new `User`, creating a new `ErrorEvent` can be linked to that user, since it each time requests the `User`s from the database.

You can subclass the `ModelChoiceField` to specify how to display the options, for example:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyUserModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f'{obj.username} ({obj.firstname} {obj.lastname})'
```

Then we can use this in the form:

```
class ErrorEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = MyUserModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ErrorEvent
        # fields =
        exclude = ['event_id']
        widgets = {
            'owner': forms.Select(),
        }
```